# how can I modify the content of GtkListStore inside a Composed Widgets after its initialisiation in julia?

Tags: julia, gtk, gtk.jl

I want to use GTK in a Julia program to display a list of properties that changes over time. I am now to both GTK and Julia

I tried to combine [the tutorial for composed widgets](https://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/manual/customWidgets/#Composed-Widgets-1) with [the one for liststore](https://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/manual/listtreeview/#List-View-1), but that didn't work, since I get errors when I try to access the ListStore from outside the struct.

For my specific purpose I don't even need to push to the listStore. It would be enough if I could modify rows that are already there. Also I am still in an early stage of development, so I am still be able to change to another gui-framework, so recommendations are also appreciated.

The following works, as I long as I don't try to access `myListStore`.

```
using Gtk

mutable struct CustomStore <: Gtk.GtkListStore
    handle::Ptr{Gtk.GObject}
    listStore
    # listStore::Gtk.GtkListStoreLeaf
    # listStore::Ptr{Gtk.GObject}

    function CustomStore()
        container = GtkBox(:v)
        infoLabel= GtkLabel("container")
        push!(container, infoLabel)

        listStore = GtkListStore(String, Int)
        push!(listStore,("aaa",123))
        push!(listStore,("bbb",234))

        print("typeof(listStore): ")
        println(typeof(listStore)) # typeof(listStore): GtkListStoreLeaf

        tv = GtkTreeView(GtkTreeModel(listStore))
        rTxt = GtkCellRendererText()
        c1 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Name", rTxt, Dict([("text",0)]))
        c2 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Value", rTxt, Dict([("text",1)]))
        push!(tv, c1, c2)
        push!(container,tv)
        push!(listStore,("ccc",345))

        print("typeof(listStore): ")
        println(typeof(listStore)) # typeof(listStore): GtkListStoreLeaf

        return Gtk.gobject_move_ref(new(container.handle), container)
    end
end

function main()
    win = GtkWindow("My First Gtk.jl Program", 800, 600)
    myStore = CustomStore()
    push!(win, myStore)
    showall(win)
      
    # Some things I tried but yielded errors:
    # myListStore::GtkTreeStore = getproperty(myStore, :ts) 
    # myListStore::GtkListStoreLeaf = getproperty(myStore, :ts) 
    # myListStore = get_gtk_property(myStore,:ts,String) 

    myListStore = getproperty(myStore, :ts)
    print("typeof(myListStore): ")
    println(typeof(myListStore)) # typeof(myListStore): Gtk.GLib.FieldRef{CustomStore}


    println("Here is what my goal is: Modifying the listStore after the custom widget has been initialized: ")
    # push!(myListStore,("zzz",999))
    # --> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching push!(::Gtk.GLib.FieldRef{CustomStore}, ::Tuple{String, Int64})
    # Closest candidates are:
    #   push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at /opt/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/abstractarray.jl:2952
    #   push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at /opt/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/abstractarray.jl:2953
    #   push!(::GtkTreeStore, ::Tuple) at ~/.julia/packages/Gtk/B6LVT/src/lists.jl:224
    
    
    if !isinteractive()
        @async Gtk.gtk_main()
        Gtk.waitforsignal(win,:destroy)
    end    
end

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you should return the new() struct as you declared it: a handle and a list store.

You also sometimes need to update the window after you change the listing.  Hiding and showing the window should do this:

```
using Gtk

mutable struct CustomStore <: Gtk.GtkListStore
    handle::Ptr{GObject}
    listStore::GtkListStoreLeaf
    function CustomStore()
        container = GtkBox(:v)
        infoLabel= GtkLabel("container")
        push!(container, infoLabel)

        listStore = GtkListStore(String, Int)
        push!(listStore,("aaa",123))
        push!(listStore,("bbb",234))

        print("typeof(listStore): ")
        println(typeof(listStore)) # typeof(listStore): GtkListStoreLeaf

        tv = GtkTreeView(GtkTreeModel(listStore))
        rTxt = GtkCellRendererText()
        c1 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Name", rTxt, Dict([("text",0)]))
        c2 = GtkTreeViewColumn("Value", rTxt, Dict([("text",1)]))
        push!(tv, c1, c2)
        push!(container,tv)
        push!(listStore,("ccc",345))

        print("typeof(listStore): ")
        println(typeof(listStore)) # typeof(listStore): GtkListStoreLeaf

        return Gtk.gobject_move_ref(new(container.handle, listStore), container)
    end
end

function main()
    win = GtkWindow("My First Gtk.jl Program", 800, 600)
    myStore = CustomStore()
    push!(win, myStore)
    showall(win)

    println("Here is what my goal is: Modifying the listStore after the custom widget has been initialized: ")
    push!(myStore.listStore,("zzz",999))
    hide(win)
    show(win)

    if !isinteractive()
        @async Gtk.gtk_main()
        Gtk.waitforsignal(win,:destroy)
    end
end

main()
```

Comment: Thanks. Up until now I didn't look at how constructors work in julia. I have a question still the gtk.jl doc said that the gobject_move_ref-call is needed for something that I didn't quite understand. Am I correct to assume that I can recreate the function of gobject_move_ref simple by wrapping the new-constructur in it like so: `return Gtk.gobject_move_ref(new(container.handle, listStore), container)`?

Comment: Ah, yes you can. That is recommended becuase it may keep the reference to container in your code's constructor from being garbage collected until the CustomStore is out of scope. I'll edit that here.

Comment: thanks. this works like a charm and I learned something `new()`.